# How can I add a svg as content on :before pseudo element of an element?

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to use a svg inside content of `:before` pseudo element.

For this purpose, I am following this question: [Is there a way to use SVG as content in a pseudo element :before or :after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255296/is-there-a-way-to-use-svg-as-content-in-a-pseudo-element-before-or-after) but I cannot make it work.

I just have a simple SVG:

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

And here is what I have tried:

**Example 1: Inserting the svg on the content attribute**

```css
#square{
   background-color: green;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}

#square:before{
   display: block;
   content: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg height='100' width='100'><circle cx='50' cy='50' r='40' stroke='black' stroke-width='3' fill='red' /></svg>");
   background-size: 28px 28px;
   height: 28px;
   width: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div id="square"></div>
```

**Example 2: With base64 encoding**

```css
#square{
   background-color: green;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}

#square:before{
   display: block;
   content: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCI+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iNTAiIGN5PSI1MCIgcj0iNDAiIHN0cm9rZT0iYmxhY2siIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iMyIgZmlsbD0icmVkIiAvPjwvc3ZnPg==");
   background-size: 28px 28px;
   height: 28px;
   width: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div id="square"></div>
```

As you can see, any of those examples does not work so I am sure that I am missing something.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might need to be an actual URL. In chrome it complains saying its not a valid URL. Make that content a SVG file like content.svg and link to that in URL and it should work.

Comment: @Deckerz I have tried using `content: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,content.svg");` and also `content: url("content.svg");` but none of those methods worked.

Comment: @Deckerz Ok, Niloct gave me the clue of what I was missing. It seems that I was missing mandatory attributes.

Comment: @LGSon Why is this question duplicate? I mention the other question here and I have a specific problem that Niloct pointed out so I do not think this is really a duplicate because in the other question anyone mention about those attributes that are needed.

Comment: The accepted answer clearly show the structure of the SVG, hence it qualifies as a dupe. Also, in that same answer they didn't mention the lack of using `url()` with `content: ...`, which were what the dupe question asked, they simply used it in their sample. So the here given answer, together with the dupe link, complements each other.

Comment: @LGSon It is ok, now I see what you mean. I did not notice that those attributes were needed. Thanks for the explanation about why you marked it as duplicate :)

Comment: Thanks, upvoted your question ... and a dupe link draws attention to both this and the other post, which is great :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Seems like the `SVG` tag needed more attributes.

```css
#square{
   background-color: green;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}

#square:before{
   display: block;
   content: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8, <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='100' width='100'><circle cx='50' cy='50' r='40' stroke='black' stroke-width='3' fill='red' /></svg>");
   background-size: 28px 28px;
   height: 28px;
   width: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div id="square"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very my much! Adding `xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1'` seems to be the clue!

Comment: You're welcome :)