# IE not displaying SVG as content in a pseudo element :before or :after

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, internet-explorer-11

This problem is a extension of below thread.
[Is there a way to use SVG as content in a pseudo element :before or :after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255296/is-there-a-way-to-use-svg-as-content-in-a-pseudo-element-before-or-after).

I am trying to attach a svg triangle after a div using pseudo class.

```css
div{
background-color: black;
width: 48px;
height: 45px;
}

div::before{
content: url('data:image/svg+xml; utf8, <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="266.53926701570674 152.66492146596858 44 44"><defs><path d="M267.54 153.66L307.54 193.66L267.54 193.66L267.54 153.66Z" id="d6AN4MEUYO"></path></defs><g><g><use xlink:href="#d6AN4MEUYO" opacity="1" fill="red" fill-opacity="1"></use></g></g></svg>');
right: -47px;
position: relative;

}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The above code is working good in chrome but when it comes to IE it is not loading the svg content.

I also tried with background-image property but it seems to not work in IE(version > 10).

What is the right way to append this svg as a content with pseudo classes?

Comment: Which version of IE? Also, it's not working in your snippet in Chrome either.

Comment: Note `IE9-Edge12, Safari 5.1-6, and UCWeb 11 do not support referencing external files via <use xlink:href>`... just use regular svg and it will work, also specify height, width... check [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg).

Comment: @Paulie_D I am using IE version 11

Comment: Unrelated to the answer, but pseudo elements should be marked with a double colon `.class::after` instead of single colon `.class:after`. Pseudo classes are marked with single colons. Source https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements#Syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested it with IE 11 and I am able to produce the issue. It seems that the pseudo-elements content attribute do not currently work on SVG elements. It can be possible that it is some kind of bug or it is IE browser default behavior. I will try to submit the feedback regarding this issue.

As a workaround, I suggest you display the svg content using background-image attribute, like this:

```
<style>
    .div1:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        height: 80px;
        width: 80px;
        background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20height%3D%2280%22%20width%3D%22160%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%2240%22%20cy%3D%2240%22%20r%3D%2238%22%20stroke%3D%22black%22%20stroke-width%3D%221%22%20fill%3D%22red%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%22120%22%20cy%3D%2240%22%20r%3D%2238%22%20stroke%3D%22black%22%20stroke-width%3D%221%22%20fill%3D%22blue%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E);
    }
</style>
<div class="div1" style="background-color:green; width:80px;height:80px"></div>
```

The result in IE 11 browser as below:

[image]

Edit:

> I am not able to use my svg with background-image property whereas
>   your svg is loading with the property. Is there any problem with my
>   svg?

When we use SVG with background-image property, we should ensure that [reserved URL characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) are encoded (e.g. `<` === `%3C` and `>` === `%3E`) and also replace the space with '%20'.

So, please encode your svg element as below:

```
background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22xMidYMid%20meet%22%20viewBox%3D%22266.53926701570674%20152.66492146596858%2044%2044%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M267.54%20153.66L307.54%20193.66L267.54%20193.66L267.54%20153.66Z%22%20id%3D%22d6AN4MEUYO%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D%22%23d6AN4MEUYO%22%20opacity%3D%221%22%20fill%3D%22red%22%20fill-opacity%3D%221%22%3E%3C%2Fuse%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E);
```

Then, the result like this:

[image]

Comment: I am not able to use my svg with background-image property whereas your svg is loading with the property. Is there any problem with my svg?

Comment: @ Onera, please check the Edit to encode the svg element.

Comment: I used https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/ link to encode svg. Thanks