# Pass React component to CSS psuedo-element content attribute

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, emotion

I have a typescript file that builds css using [Emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction).

Can I pass a custom React component to  css psuedo-element content like this:
This customReactComponent is an SvgImage wrapped as a ReactComponent.

```
  &:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '${(<CustomReactComponent />)}';   
  }
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What happens when you try to pass it as above?

Comment: Code doesn't compile

Comment: You might be able to use an `svg` as is, without a component - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255296/is-there-a-way-to-use-svg-as-content-in-a-pseudo-element-before-or-after

Comment: it is not possible to use `React` component as `content` according to [the mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content), however you can put your React component inside div and then use it in styles