# Replace the 'Tick' mark of a HTML check box with an image or any other symbol

Tags: html, css

How can I have a different graphic (image or another symbol) rather than the default `Tick` mark in the HTML check box.

I read many SO questions but could not do that. As I saw [this question to change the color of the tick mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639373/css-html-how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-check-mark-within-the-checkbox-input) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css). All are old questions. But it's too complex.

Is there any simple way to do this. I hope there is a simple and better way now ?

Comment: nope.. still the same way..

Answer (score 18):

Actually, theres an easy way to do this using CSS and pseudo-elements. I am using `content` to add a checkmark in Unicode, but you could use a background just as well, just make sure the positioning is correct.

This implementation **requires nothing but having a checkbox** itself, so no *additional `label`* etc... Your text label will even function correctly from anywhere!

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{
    -webkit-appearance: initial;
    appearance: initial;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    background: gray;
    position: relative;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    background: red;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
    /* Heres your symbol replacement - this is a tick in Unicode. */
    content: "\2713";
    color: #fff;
    /* The following positions my tick in the center, 
     * but you could just overlay the entire box
     * with a full after element with a background if you want to */
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    /*
     * If you want to fully change the check appearance, use the following:
     * content: " ";
     * width: 100%;
     * height: 100%;
     * background: blue;
     * top: 0;
     * left: 0;
     */
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Base for label styling */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* checkbox aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:0; top: 2px;
  width: 17px; height: 17px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3)
}
/* checked mark aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  content: '✔';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #09ad7e;
  transition: all .2s;
}
/* checked mark aspect changes */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
/* disabled checkbox */
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:before {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #bbb;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:after {
  color: #999;
}
[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
  color: #aaa;
}
/* accessibility */
[type="checkbox"]:checked:focus + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked):focus + label:before {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}

/* hover style just for information */
label:hover:before {
  border: 1px solid #4778d9!important;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test1" />
    <label for="test1">Red</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test2" checked="checked" />
    <label for="test2">Yellow</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test3" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
    <label for="test3">Green</label>
  </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="test4" disabled="disabled" />
      <label for="test4">Brown</label>
  </p>
</form>
```

This is very simple and pure html and css example for custom checkboxes.