# Custom checkbox character

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to replace the HTML checkbox character with a simpler/straighter checkmark character, like so:

[image]

Since I'm styling the checkbox in pure CSS, I've tried changing the `font-family` on `content: '\2713'` and `content: '\2714'` no no avail. Can anything else be used?

Comment: you can either set a background image for `checked`, or use svg to animate  the whole thing

Comment: http://www.csscheckbox.com/ might help

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639373/css-html-how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-check-mark-within-the-checkbox-input. Demo of the link : http://jsfiddle.net/5g3w32ug/

Comment: @er-han This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: something like this, https://lokesh-coder.github.io/pretty-checkbox/  ?